# Error while installing Oracle Development Tools 18.3.0.0.0 for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

While Installing the Oracle Development Tools for VS 2017, I came upon this error message and I have not been able solve it so far.

[Error Message pointing me to a log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zjxv.png)

The error Message points me to a log file in which the following stacktrace is found:

`1/9/2020 3:39:09 PM - System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.OperationCanceledException: Pre-check verification failed with warning(s) :  AnotherInstallationRunning. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.CanceledByPrecheckException: Pre-check verification failed with warning(s) :  AnotherInstallationRunning.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PrecheckManager.RunPrechecks(PrecheckParameters precheckParameters, VariableCollection properties)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunPrecheck(String destination, Product product, ExecuteAction action, IWindowsRestartManager rmService, ITelemetryOperation installOperation, InstallOperation install)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.<Install>b__14_0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.Install()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionBatchEngine.Execute(List1 installableExtensions, Version targetVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BatchEngineInstall(List1 installableExtensions, InstallFlags installFlags, Version targetVsVersion)
   at VSIXInstaller.BatchSetupEngineInstaller.Install(SupportedVSSKU sku, List1 extensionsToInstall, InstallFlags installFlags)
   at VSIXInstaller.BatchSetupEngineInstaller.BatchInstall(IReadOnlyList1 targetSkus, IEnumerable1 extensionsToInstall)
   at VSIXInstaller.SilentEngine.Execute(ExtensionData data)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.OperationCanceledException: Pre-check verification failed with warning(s) :  AnotherInstallationRunning. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.CanceledByPrecheckException: Pre-check verification failed with warning(s) :  AnotherInstallationRunning.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PrecheckManager.RunPrechecks(PrecheckParameters precheckParameters, VariableCollection properties)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunPrecheck(String destination, Product product, ExecuteAction action, IWindowsRestartManager rmService, ITelemetryOperation installOperation, InstallOperation install)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.<Install>b__14_0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)<---`

The gist of it in my understanding is that there is another installation running while it tries to install the Visual Studio extension. I didn't of course install something myself during the process, but I also checked the task manager if there is ein msiexec process running. Sometimes there was one running but I got the same error message while there was no msiexec process running.

The only way I can imagine two installers running is that the Oracle Development Tools installer starts the Visual Studio extension installer. Then there are two installers running. However I do not quite believe in that conclusion as this should have been occurred somewhere else before but I haven't found my error message anywhere.

The things I have tried:

- Multiple Reinstall with restarts and running as admin.
- I have tried to manuelly install the extension after the error occurs, which ends successfully, however when I try to use the custom tools in visual studio I get an error message.

Visual Studio 2017 Verison: 15.9.18

Oracle Development Tools Version: 18.3.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

In my case the execution of the following file solved this issue:

Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0.vsix

Here you can find this file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle Developer Tools for VS2017\odt